# Rails 3 link_to question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

So lets say I have the following route in my routes.rb file -

```
get 'site/user/:id' => 'users#show', :as => :get_user
```

How do I use **link_to** create a link to a particular user id by using named route :get_user

```
# so this will spit out "site/user", but i want /site/user/23 as output
link_to 'Some User', :get_user
```

NOTE -: I dont want to map user as a resource in my routes file. Also "user" object is a hash not an instance of my User model.

For now this is what I have. Looking for a cleaner approach, is there any?

```
link_to 'Some User', {:controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => "#{user[:id]}"}
```

I am on Rails v3.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_user_path(user[:id])` should work since you're using a hash rather than an ActiveRecord model.

Answer (score 1):

`get_user_path(user)` should work.

(Assuming `user` is an instance of your User model.)

Comment: @user310525 Yes and no. `*_path` accepts integers, not just records. `get_user_path(user[:id])` would work.